# Etymology of the term "flag" in programming

Tags: boolean, history, flags

Every now and then i find a boolean variable named "flag", mostly by novice programmers. I always tell them every boolean is a flag, and variables should have meaningful names. So i was wondering what is the etymology behind the term "flag".

Maybe its something obvious, my guess is it comes from a military context, but i would like to know the real history behind it. And by the way i tried to sum it up in the title, but i'm making the question a bit lengthy because i get a warning about quality standards. Sorry for that.

Anyway, what's the story behind the "flag" term ?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about programming terminology. It may be more suitable for [programmers.se].

Comment: You might also find http://english.stackexchange.com a good place to look. According to [the dictionary](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/flag), the verb means _"to mark or identify..."_. Since a mark is binary (its only significant property being its presence/absence), it makes sense that a boolean would be called a "flag".

Comment: ok, just to clarify a bit, i'm a native spanish speaker, and in spanish the translation is "bandera" which is a noun, and can´t be used as a verb. but in english that would make perfect sense. still i think it is an analogy of something from another context, but thanks anyway

Comment: i'd like to reopen the question because i don't think there are many answers or the good answer is too long, in fact i think i have found the right answer, which i would like to share. it seems like it comes from railway signalling according to this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Railway_signalling : "A mounted flagman on a horse preceded some early trains. Hand and arm signals were used to direct the “train drivers”. Foggy and poor-visibility conditions gave rise to flags and lanterns. Wayside signalling dates back as far as 1832, and used elevated flags or balls that could be seen from afar."

Comment: I dont understand, why nobody answer this questions, this is a good question